# Skip part of query if item text is empty

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query

```
            return uow.CustomerRepo
            .Get()
            .Where
            (
                c=>
                    c.Firstname.StartsWith(customerSearch.Initial) &&
                    c.Surname  == customerSearch.Surname           &&                        
                    c.Email    == customerSearch.Email             &&
                    c.Postcode == customerSearch.PostCode
            )
```

Is there a way to skip parts of the query if something in `customerSearch` is empty?

so I want to skip the part

```
c.Surname  == customerSearch.Surname
```

if

```
customerSearch.Surname
```

Is empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a condition that checks the `customerSearch` part explicitly:

```
.Where
(
    c=>
        (customerSearch.Initial == null || c.Firstname.StartsWith(customerSearch.Initial)) &&
        (customerSearch.Surname == null || c.Surname  == customerSearch.Surname)           &&                        
        (customerSearch.Email == null || c.Email    == customerSearch.Email)             &&
        (customerSearch.PostCode == null || c.Postcode == customerSearch.PostCode)
)
```

If you need to check for empty strings rather than `null`, change the condition accordingly.

Comment: I'd recommend `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`